# Stop initialization of ruby object

Tags: ruby, object-oriented-analysis

Which is the best practice to not save an object because does not pass certain validations?

I have done this class:

```
class Articles
  attr_reader :doi, :title, :issn

  def initialize data, doi_validator: Validators::Doi.new, title_validator: Validators::Title.new, issn_validator: Validators::Issn.new
    @doi, @title, @issn = data

    @doi_validator   = doi_validator
    @title_validator = title_validator
    @issn_validator  = issn_validator

    raise_error unless valid?
  end

  private

  def valid?
    (
      doi_validator.call(doi) && 
      title_validator.call(title) && 
      issn_validator.call(issn)
    )
  end

  attr_reader :doi_validator, :title_validator, :issn_validator
end
```

The thing is that instead of raising an error I would like the process of instantiation to be stopped without affecting the flow of the app.

Probably the best way is to check it before initializing the instantiation, but that would complicate pretty much the application. Is there any way you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like

```
article = Articles.new(data)
```

then there are only two possibilities:

- an exception is raised; `article =` assignment does not happen. You need to catch the exception.
- an exception is not raised; `article` now contains an `Article` object (possibly invalid).

You could walk the middle ground and make a new class method:

```
class Article
  def self.new_if_valid(*args)
    self.new(*args)
  rescue InitializationInvalidError
    nil
  end
end
class InitializationInvalidError < StandardError; end
```

EDIT: Actually, you could even make it a mixin, it is general enough:

```
module NilIfInitializationFails
  def self.new_if_valid(*args)
    self.new(*args)
  rescue InitializationInvalidError
    nil
  end
end
class InitializationInvalidError < StandardError; end

class Article
  include NilIfInitializationFails
  # ....
end
```

Comment: Hi @Amadan, thank you very much for the answer. I am not sure If I see the benefit of wrapping this into a module. Could you give me more reasons?

Comment: As a module, you can reuse it in any number of classes by just putting the one line into the class (`include NilIfInitializationFails`).